# BigQuery/Google Data Studio: Counting orders from first purchase to max date on date range filter

Tags: looker-studio

I am using BigQuery and Google Data Studio to build a table that shows customers total orders from their first purchase to the max date selected on the date range filter.

This is the sample dataset I have

[image]

This is the output I want

[image]

Comment: How do you get the "First Order Date" for each customer? It's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69589274/getting-first-purchase-date-for-each-customer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Data Studio supports this. Is it an option to always use some old date like `01/01/1970` (set it as default) as the first date on the date range? That way you can just add `Customer Id` and `First Order Date` as Dimensions and `count(Order Date)` as Metric.