# getting first purchase date for each customer

Tags: filter, looker-studio

I want to get the first order date for each customer in a new field in Google Data Studio.

For example, I want this result:

| cust_id | order_id | order_dateTime | first_order_dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | wer | 09/13/2018 2:23:10 PM | 09/13/2018 2:23:10 PM |
| a1 | sdf | 09/13/2018 2:25:07 PM | 09/13/2018 2:23:10 PM |
| a1 | aqf | 11/24/2018 9:11:43 AM | 09/13/2018 2:23:10 PM |
| b7 | nmk | 02/15/2018 7:40:14 AM | 02/15/2018 7:40:14 AM |
| c41 | dst | 03/08/2019 1:33:14 PM | 03/08/2019 1:33:14 PM |
| c41 | mvh | 04/23/2020 7:51:21 AM | 03/08/2019 1:33:14 PM |

I get it in Power BI using this code:

```
first_order_dateTime = CALCULATE(min('table'[order_dateTime]) , ALLEXCEPT('table', 'table'[cust_id]))
```

but I don't know How can I get it in google data studio.

Note that I want the first_order_dateTime field in DateTime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this result you need to do:

Create a data combination, combining the base with itself. In the combination, use the `cust_id` binding key. In the base to the right, insert the dimension `order_dateTime`, in the base to the left insert the metric with aggregation of type MIN to `order_dateTime`, calling this metric `first_order_dateTime`.

After performing the combination, just insert your data into a table to view the result, inserting the `cust_id`, `order_daterTime` and `first_order_dateTime` columns.

[image]]

Comment: You're right but In this way, How can I get second_order_dateTime? I know it's a separate question.